# How to select concrete Pod from StatefulSet and assign it to concrete Node

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

Good day, does kubernetes `StatefulSet` has an option for set concrete Pod to concrete Node.

For example: we have `StatefulSet` that contained 3 replicas of `Pod`'s with unique labels (`app-0`, `app-1`, `app-2`) and 3 `Node`'s with labels (`node-0`, `node-1`, `node-2`). How to point on Pod from `StatefulSet` with label `app-0` to node with label `node-0`? In official documentation of StatefulSet, PodAffinity and NodeAffifnity i dont find any information how to do this.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, now in Kubernetes v1.10 there’s no instrument to do this, but anyway, with pod affinity, you can distribute your pods on each node, and if memory serves me, in StatefulSets you have absolutely the same pod. It is not critical if pod app-1 is stored on node-2 and pod app-2 on node-1 because you still have the same two pods on 2 different nodes, haven’t you?

Comment: Thank's for your answer, it very helpful!  Thanks a lot!